# Drupal 8 Link Autocomplete Filter by Bundle

Tags: navigation

Does anyone know how to limit the autocomplete suggestions of Link Fields to only certain bundles -- not globally, but per Link Field instance? I nearly found a solution in customizing https://github.com/minnur/Alter-Entity-Autocomplete , but this is global for all autocompletes, and I need to get the calling Link Field instance somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the following contributed module to solve the issue:

[Link Field Autocomplete Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_field_autocomplete_filter)

> This module adds a Link Field configuration for filtering the allowed
>   content types in the autocomplete field.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with hook form alter:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // if $form_id ==  'xyz'
  $form['field_mylink']['widget'][0]['uri']['#selection_handler']="default:node";
  $form['field_mylink']['widget'][0]['uri']['#selection_settings']=[
    'target_bundles'=>['article'=>'article', 'page'=>'page'], //etc
  ];

}
```